# Как запустить функцию в другом потоке, не останавливая бота?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть бот, в котором при нажатии на кнопку начинается длительный процесс.
Бот написан на aiogram второй версии.
Запускаемая функция является async, но в ней есть вложенная синхронная.

```
 await pars(call.message.chat.id)
```

Так вызывается основная функция

внутри этой async функции вызывается другая, следующим образом:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(parse_ad, link, count_links_parsed) for link in ad_links]
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        ad_data, count_links_parsed = future.result()
        ads.append(ad_data)
```

Как вызывать эти функции не останавливая работу бота? Может, есть способ создания очередей/еще что-то?

Comment: Для вызова синхронного кода используйте run_in_executor или типа того